# Proxy not returning Web app content

Tags: apache-2.4

I have a webapp which communicates to the end user over port 80 and to an Express Server over port 3001. I've set up a [reverse proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/897896/forward-or-reverse-proxy) but the code seems to be returning my server response directly to my end user instead of the web app html code. I need the web app to continue sending it's typical html response while sending it's server api requests to port 3001. Have I setup my proxy incorrectly?

The tricky thing here is that my web app is acting as both Server (to the end user) and client (to the Express server).

Here's my vhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ServerName 192.168.253.101
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/request.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/Client_Cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/Client_Key.key"
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPass / https://localhost:3001/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:443/
</VirtualHost>
```

[Diagram of](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjGrK.png)

Comment: That `<Proxy *>` section is dangerous and should not be present. It makes your web server an open proxy, a misconfigured _forward_ proxy which anyone on the Internet can abuse to hide their own network location and perform malicious activity and have that activity attributed to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the line ProxyPass to ProxyPassMatch allowed me to still access my HTML page from the root domain while passing any additional api calls to my server listening.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
    ServerName 192.168.253.101
    ServerAlias example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/example.com/request.log combined
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/ssl/certs/Client_Cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/ssl/certs/Client_Key.key"
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy "*">
           Require host yournetwork.example.com
        </Proxy>
       ProxyPassMatch ^/([a-z]+)$ https://localhost:3001/$1
</VirtualHost>
```